# How to edit Coded UI Log file(UITestActionLog.html) for customizing the log details?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am using VS2012 Premium for Creating coded UI Tests. I am able to create "UITestActionLog.html" by enabling Logging.

Is there any way, So that i can Customize Description of Actions in this Log File.
Can we edit description about actions in the Log file being generated.

Quicker Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I asked the same question...we should combine Here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085091/can-we-add-custom-action-to-htmlloggerstate)