# Can we add custom action to HtmlLoggerState

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm using VS2013/CodedUI and my palybacksetting is as follow:

```
 Playback.PlaybackSettings.LoggerOverrideState = HtmlLoggerState.AllActionSnapshot;
```

I also have a 3rd party tool that I have integrated to my code that does some action that codedui can't...Iw an to be able to log those steps into the ActionLog.html file with where codedui capture the actions and screenshot.

I searched a lot but didn't find anything on how we can achieve this.

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I think we need to do some custom development for this. I will develop something that can write to an HTML file as suggested in this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a53ddcf4-11f7-4586-8256-c4e238dc192a/is-it-possible-to-write-message-into-uitestactionlog?forum=vstest)

Answer (score 0):

I posted a response over here: [Writing Custom HTML Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130028/writing-custom-html-logs/26120973#26120973)

It sounds like there's not a good way to do this. You can get the path to where the html file lives and write a custom logger from there. I'm not sure it'd be safe to try and write to it while your test is executing, but perhaps once your test is complete.

Comment: Indeed, but we actually think that we found another way! We haven't got time to try it out yet but we think it would work. We can use the built in classes that are responsible to write to the HTMllogger. We would need t use reflection to be able to access the functionality of those dlls and we could override some of the functions. When we get to this ill update this post.